# Finding Mean Absolute Deviation in Holtwinter

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Let's say our dataset looks as follows;

```
demand <- ts(BJsales, start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 12)
plot(demand)
```

Now I pass the timeseries object to HoltWinter and plot the fitted data.

```
hw <- HoltWinters(demand)
plot(hw)
```

I want to difference Demand and fitted data to find Mean Absolute Deviation(MAD).
I took the demand by `hw$x`
I took the fit by `hw$fit`

```
accu_Holt_data <- as.data.frame(hw$x)
 fore_holt <- as.data.frame(hw$fit)
differnce <- accu_Holt_data - fore_holt
```

cant difference as row length is different

Comment: hw$fit is a multi-column dataframe also if you look at the date index for hw$fit you will see it's not the same as hw$x. You could do something like this however, `cbind(hw$fit[, 1], hw$x)` and use that to calculate MAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my comment above, you can do something like this:

```
dta <- cbind(hw$fit[, 1], hw$x)
mean(abs(dta[, 2] - dta[, 1]), na.rm = TRUE)
```

There are two main issues with your approach: First, hw$fit is a multi-column dataframe where the first column, xhat, represents the filtered series. Second, the two times series have different indices. Hence the need for someting like cbind to merge the time series.